# Finding the value of a fraction according to a given information

Tags: fractions

$a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers such that:
$abc=ab+ac+bc$. Find the value of $\frac{a+b}{b}+\frac{a+c}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}$.

I've tried simplifying the expression and eventually I got:

$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+2$, but I couldn't keep up.

Comment: **Hint**: divide by $abc$ your first equality.

Comment: I did that, and I got $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(a+b)/b + (a+c)/c + (c+b)/a

abc= ab+bc+ac (divide by abc)

this means
1= 1/a + 1/b + 1/c

if a=b=c then answer is 6

in all other cases the answers are infinite
for ex a=2,b=4,c=4 answer is 6.5 and a=2 b=3 c=6 answer is = 7.5

Comment: Thanks you so much